# Python doing those two things at a time, multitasking or not?

Tags: python

EDIT

from manish and njzk2 suggestion:

now i recall trying to use when_motion but getting:

type error: 'NoneType' object is not callable

when put in the fonction.

Putting it outside the function like you suggest seemed a good idea, but the error still pop and interrupt .inventory()
also the sound is playing instantly although no motion occurred

what i've done:

```
from PN5180 import PN5180
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import vlc

player = vlc.MediaPlayer()

def play(element):
    print ("{}!".format(element))
    player.set_media(vlc.Media("{}.wav".format(element)))
    player.play()

while True:
      
      
    cards = PN5180().inventory()
    print(f"{len(cards)} card(s) detected: {' - '.join(cards)}")
    cardcount = len(cards)
    
    MotionSensor(17).when_motion(Play("feu"))
```

still getting error:

MotionSensor(17).when_motion(Play("feu"))

type error: 'NoneType' object is not callable

even in the simplest context:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor

While true:

    MotionSensor(17).when_motion()
    print("motion detected")
```

the error is return.

What does it means?

---

i'm currently trying to set my first python/raspberry pi project up

in order to interface a rfid reader,
i'm using this library: https://github.com/fservida/pyPN5180

it consiste in one usable methode that returne a list up to 16 nfc presents chips.
for what i understand in order for it to update you need to put it in a loop.

```
from PN5180 import PN5180

reader = PN5180

 while True:
        cards = reader.inventory() #getting the list
        print(f"{len(cards)} card(s) detected: {' - '.join(cards)}")
        time.sleep(.4)
```

i'd like to listen constantly for chips while also listening for movement on 3 motion sensors

but if i add my sensor function

```
from PN5180 import PN5180

reader = PN5180

 while True:
        cards = reader.inventory() #getting the list
        print(f"{len(cards)} card(s) detected: {' - '.join(cards)}")
        time.sleep(.4)

        mySensorFonction()
```

Then cards list does'nt iterate/update anymore, and putting cards on the reader doesn't trigger anything that i call

here's the sensor function just in case:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import vlc

player = vlc.MediaPlayer()

def PirSound(pin, element):
    
    pir = MotionSensor(pin=pin)
    pir.wait_for_motion()
    print ("{}!".format(element))
    player.set_media(vlc.Media("{}.wav".format(element)))
    player.play()
```

i'd like the list of detected chip updating constantly while doing other things and be able to pickup what's inside the list anytime i want to trigger events and states

doing a quick search i stumble upon the mutitasking library.
is it the solution for me? how would you set this up?

hope it's clear enough ^^

Comment: In your motion sensor code, I think you have a blocking wait on `wait_for_motion()`. So, when your while loop starts, it scans for a card immediately enters the motion sensor code and then gets stuck on waiting for motion sensor. The while loop never goes to the next iteration and your cards are not read

Comment: Try to keep a card on the reader, and then activate the motion sensor. Do you see the card detected?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
def play():
    print ("{}!".format(element))
    player.set_media(vlc.Media("{}.wav".format(element)))
    player.play()

and 

pir.when_motion(play)
```

instead of calling `wait_for_motion()`.

`wait_for_motion` is blocking (...it wait for a motion), while `when_motion` registers a callback that is called when a motion is detected.

Comment: now i recall trying to use when_motion but getting:

type error: 'NoneType' object is not callable

when put in the fonction.
putting it outside de fonction like you suggest seemed a good idea, but the error still pop and interupt .inventory()

Comment: `when_motion(play("feu"))` doesn't work because `play("feu")` is not a function, it's the return value of the function. You need to pass the function itself (`play`), not the result of an invocation

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, what you're looking for is multi-threading, the multi threading implementation in python is called threading, here's a nice explanation + tutorial from Geeks for Geeks [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/)

Comment: while factually accurate, it doesn't address the main issue: using a blocking call to the motion sensor is not necessary.